# How to print the selected value of Dropdown

Tags: spfx, dropdown, sharepoint-framework, spfx-custom-property-pane

I would like to know if there is a way to print the selected value of a Dropdown menu that is inside the Property Pane in SPFX.

Like, in my case, how to make it print with a *console.log* "Ascending" or "Descending" when selected from the Dropdown, or at least the respective key ('ASC' or 'DES')

**Here is my code:**

```
PropertyPaneDropdown('ItemsDropDown',{  
    label: "Sort by",  
    options: [
        { key: 'ASC', text: 'Ascending' },
        { key: 'DES', text: 'Descending' }
    ],
    selectedKey: strings.SelectedKeyDropdown,
})
```

**Here is a screenshoot of my Dropdown**

[image]

Comment: Which framework are you using, ReactJS?

Comment: Pure Sharepoint Framework, nothing else

Comment: Or, willman, if you know a way of doing it using React I will really appreciate it if you tell me!